# List<A> into List<B> java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.business.impl.MeteobussinesImpl.afficherMeteo1(MeteobussinesImpl.java:34)
>   at com.test.Tester.main(Tester.java:32)
>   1.Main Class
>       package com.test;

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.business.Meteobussines;
import com.business.impl.MeteobussinesImpl;
import com.model.vo.Meteo;

public class Tester {
    static public void displayList(List list) {
        Iterator iter = list.iterator();
        if (!iter.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("La lsite est vide");
            return;
        }
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Meteo ct = (Meteo) iter.next();
            System.out.println("tempsMax :" + ct.getTempMax() + " pays :" + ct.getLibilePays() + "  distination :" + ct.getLibileDistination());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[] configArray = new String[]{"/com/resource/spring/ApplicationContext.xml",
                "/com/resource/spring/ApplicationContextDao.xml", "/com/resource/spring/ApplicationContextBusiness.xml"};

        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(configArray);

        Meteobussines mete = (Meteobussines) ctx.getBean("MeteoBuss");
        List<Meteo> m = mete.afficherMeteo1("tounes");
        displayList(m);

    }

}
```

2.MeteoBussiness

```
package com.business.impl;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.business.Meteobussines;
import com.dao.HistoriqueDao;
import com.dao.impl.HistoriqueDaoImpl;
import com.model.dto.Historique;
import com.model.vo.Meteo;

public class MeteobussinesImpl implements Meteobussines {

    HistoriqueDao historiqueDao;

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    @Override
    public List<Meteo> afficherMeteo1(String pays) {
        List<Historique> hiss = historiqueDao.rechercher(pays);
        List<Meteo> m = null;
        Iterator iter = hiss.iterator();
        if (!iter.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("La lsite est vide");
        }
        while (iter.hasNext()) {

            Historique ct = (Historique) iter.next();
            Meteo me = new Meteo();
            me.setDateHis(ct.getDateHis());
                /*me.setLibileDistination(ct.getDistination().getLibileDis());
                me.setLibilePays(ct.getPays().getLibilePays());
                me.setLibileVille(ct.getVille().getLibileVille());*/
            me.setTempMax(ct.getTempMax());
            me.setTempMin(ct.getTempMin());
            m.add(me);

        }
        return m;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public List<Meteo> afficherMeteo2(String pays, String ville) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Meteo> afficherMeteo3(String pays, String ville,
                                      String distination) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public HistoriqueDao getHistoriqueDao() {
        return historiqueDao;
    }

    public void setHistoriqueDao(HistoriqueDao historiqueDao) {
        this.historiqueDao = historiqueDao;
    }

}
```

Comment: Before using Spring and Hibernate, you should learn to format your code correctly. The you should practice with basic Java exercises to learn how to read a stack trace and understand NullPointerExceptions. It seems like you want to drive an Airbus while you just learnt to use a bike. You didn't ask anything, also.

Comment: I know that the problem is in the while bloc if you have idea and i  have to do like that because if it was dynamic web project i  don't have to use a VO :p im working in webservices projects and i have many problem in List of object if you have advice  tell me :) :)

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, you might also have more luck debugging if you remove `@SuppressWarnings("null")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `m` to `null` on line 20, and then try to call a method on it on line 34 without ever assigning it a real value.

I think what you want to do on line 20 is initialize `m` as

```
List<Meteo> m = new ArrayList<Meteo>();
```

Comment: how i can  set the result of List<Historique> into List<Meteo>